# Start shell script from jmeter in directory of jmx

Tags: bash, jmeter

I have got a jmeter test that needs to run a shell script before it can start. The shell script lays in the directory of the jmx file. I use an OS Process Sampler to invoke the script, but the working directory is set to the bin/ folder of apache jmeter, and thus causing an error.

Is there a property for the current directory where my jmx testplan is?

apache jmeter 2.8
on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to to it :

- Add a User Defined Variables called shellDir with value ${__P(shellDir,default folder)}
- Use it in your path as ${shellDir}/
- Define this property at startup using -JshellDir=

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

Comment: yes, it works like that, but I think I have to reference it by ${__P(shellDir,/default/path/)} like in http://tomaszwrobel.com/blog/2011/parameterizing-apache-jmeter-tests/